# ASP.NET - button visibility change in DetailsView HeaderTemplate not working in OnModeChanging handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, detailsview, aspbutton

I have this markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvDatabase" OnModeChanging="dvDatabase_ModeChanging">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
            Text="View" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Visible="false" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
            Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnEdit" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
            Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    ...
```

Then I have this C#:

```
protected void dvDatabase_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    bool isEdit = DetailsViewMode.Edit == e.NewMode;
    DetailsView view = (DetailsView)sender;
    Button viewButton = (Button)view.FindControl("btnView");
    Button editButton = (Button)view.FindControl("btnEdit");
    viewButton.Visible = isEdit;
    editButton.Visible = !isEdit;
}
```

I've done some debugging and the `Visible` property gets set correctly, but I never see the buttons change.  I hit the Edit button and I'm in edit mode, but the Edit button is still displayed and the View button is still hidden.  I've tried finding the buttons via `dvDatabase.FindControl` directly, rather than using the `object sender` variable, but that doesn't work either.  I tried to refer to the buttons with variables based on the `ID` attribute in the markup, but `btnView` and `btnEdit` variables/properties don't exist.  What's going on?

**Edit:** I switched to `OnModeChanged` as per Tim's suggestion, but the buttons still don't change.  Here's my C# now:

```
protected void dvDatabase_ModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView view = /*(DetailsView)sender*/dvDatabase;
    bool isEdit = DetailsViewMode.Edit == view.CurrentMode;
    LinkButton viewButton = (LinkButton)view.FindControl("btnView");
    LinkButton editButton = (LinkButton)view.FindControl("btnEdit");
    viewButton.Visible = isEdit;
    editButton.Visible = !isEdit;
}
```

I tried using the `object sender` as well as the `dvDatabase` class variable, but neither seemed to have an effect.

Comment: _"I tried to refer to the buttons with variables based on the ID attribute in the markup"_ What does that mean? You've said that the visible property gets set correctly, so why _"btnView and btnEdit variables/properties don't exist"_?

Comment: I can find the buttons via `FindControl`, and stepping through with the debugger I see that the values I'm setting the `Visible` property to look correct.  However, no `btnView` or `btnEdit` variable exists in my MyPage.aspx.designer.cs auto-generated class, unlike for the `DetailsView`.  This may be expected, I'm new to ASP.NET dev so I'm not sure what all variables get generated.

Comment: That is normaly since only controls which `NamingContainer` is the page itself are initialized and accessible in the designer.cs-file. All others are initialized during the page-lifecycle. Anyway, that does not explain why your buttonsdon't change their visible state. Are you databinding the `DetailsView` on postbacks somewhere? That might be a reason.

Comment: Hm, well I didn't have any mention of `IsPostBack` in my `Page_Load`, but adding `if (IsPostBack) { return; }` to the beginning of `Page_Load` didn't seem to help.

Comment: That's a good idea anyway since it probably would be the next problem. I must admit that i'm not very familiar with DetailsView(unlike FormView) but i assume that you should use the [ModeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.modechanged) event instead. [ModeChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.modechanging) is appropriate if you might want to cancel the change event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DetailsView`'s [`DataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound) event instead and only databind the DetailsView `if(!Page.IsPostback)`. You also need to handle the [`ItemCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemcommand) event to call the appropriate [`ChangeMode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.changemode.aspx) and databind the `DetailsView`.

```
protected void dvDatabase_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var view = (DetailsView)sender;
    var btnView = (Button)view.FindControl("btnView");
    var btnEdit = (Button)view.FindControl("btnEdit");
    switch (view.CurrentMode)
    { 
        case DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly:
            btnView.Visible = false;
            btnEdit.Visible = true;
            break;
        case DetailsViewMode.Edit:
            btnView.Visible = true;
            btnEdit.Visible = false;
            break;
        case DetailsViewMode.Insert:
            btnView.Visible = false;
            btnEdit.Visible = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```